# How does one show that the inclusion of circle in the punctured plan is not null bordant?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, cobordism

Let $(S^1,i)$ be a singular manifold in $\mathbb{R}^2-\{ 0 \} $ where $i$ is the inclusion map. I understand that this map is not nulhomotopic, but am unable to show how to prove that this is not null bordant (it seems to be that way from intuition). Could someone please suggest some line of approach ?

Comment: Do you see why it's not nullhomologous?

Comment: @PseudoNeo Sorry, I do not know the definition of nullhomologous . Could you advise some reference where I could learn this stuff

Comment: If it were, you could take the null-bordism and make it smooth and apply Green's theorem to see that the integral of any closed form on that circle is zero. But that's false.